# Can't boot ubuntu 18.04 after resizing ntfs partition using miniTotal partition wizard

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ntfs, resizing

I have windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 installed

I was running out of space in my root partition, so i wanted to shrink the ntfs partition and expand the root partition.
I tried to shrink using the disk manager on windows but it failed due to unmovable files. So i installed miniTools partition wizard, which successfully shrank the partition with no errors.

When i tried to boot into ubuntu, i was directed to emergency mode and couldn't boot.

The partition i shrank was on the left of the root partition

Also the ntfs partition is intact, i booted into windows and everything was fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem, i will leave the answer here hoping it might help somebody in the future.

While i was trying to backup the home partition, i noticed that the UUID of the ntfs partition changed, and i use that UUID to mount it in the fstab. That is what caused the problem, when i removed the line containing the UUID and rebooted. It worked just fine.

I guess nobody could have suggested this solution based on the info i provided in the question, but it was all i knew about the problem sooo.